# creating dynamic name array and adding dynamic elements

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

I need to have an output like this:

```
$users[$role][] = $name;
```

//for example

```
$users['admin'] = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');
```

Where the string admin is in a $role variable, and name1, name2, name3 are in a $name variable.

For knowing all the information I need 2 queries, so I was thinking about something like this:

```
$users = array();

QUERY 1  {

$users[${$role}] = array();

    QUERY 2  {

    $users[${$role}] = array_push($name);

    }

}
```

But I can't print elements and my array looks empty.
I tried with:

```
print_r($users[$role]);
```

and also by writing directly the role.

Can you guys help me? :)

Comment: Whats your expected output.Post that too

Comment: that's the first thing I wrote.. I need to have an output like this:

`$users = array();`
`$users['admin'] = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3');`
`$users['normal'] = array('name4','name5');`
`$users['moderator'] = array('name6','name7','name8');`

Comment: Then post your input

Comment: well, that's not an output. just `$users[$role][] = $name;`

Comment: check now if you got all the information :)

Comment: does anybody has an answer?

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did and it works!

```
$users = array();

QUERY 1  {

    ${$role} = array();
    array_push($users, $name);

        QUERY 2  {

        array_push(${$role}, $name);

        }

}

print_r($users);

foreach ($users as $value) {
print_r(${$value});
}
```